# Process Monitor Filters Temp File

Tags: process-monitor, procmon

[Procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is quite hard\long to type its [Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7JMm.png) over and over again 
 - especially for many **different, repeatable** tasks.

That made me wonder if anyone knows where does it store it's current Filter state. 
Whereas it is a file, or a registry key, or else.

I tried to use Procmon itself to find any (via unchecking default boxes), but have been lost in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process Monitor has a mechanism for saving multiple filter settings:

- Arrange your filter as you like
- Select menu *Filter > Save Filter...*
- Give your filter a name
- To establish again a saved files use menu *Filter > Load Filter...*
  and select your filter
- To effect the selected filter select *Filter > Reset Filter*
- You may also use *Filter > Organize Filters...* to Export a filter
  as a `.PMF` file, which can later be imported on another computer from
  this same dialog.

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't work for me; Procmon window only blinks, with no effect, no matter what Filter have been Saved.

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but this solution seems totally legit: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/438799/procmon-v382-does-not-load-saved-filters-please-fi.html#:~:text=Here's%20a%20solution

Comment: It worked for me - I described what I did in my answer, using version 3.86.